# Geared mixup disassembly

Tags: twisty-puzzles

Does anyone have resources on how to disassemble a geared mixup cube? I handed mine to a child who shifted one of the layers by one tooth and now it won’t turn I can’t figure out how to take it apart. I’m quite desperate. Any help?

Comment: Did you do any research into the question? Please [try this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbTYAS-itsw).

Comment: @WeatherVane A [Geared Mixup](https://s4.postimg.cc/566l3k1xp/DSC_0203.jpg) is different and might be more complex to assemble than a [Gear Cube](https://s1.postimg.cc/4gtsf42en/DSC_0086.jpg), though.. Then again, as Jaap mentioned, OP probably doesn't have to disassemble it. If the gear shifted without disassembling it, you should be able to shift it back likewise without disassembling it.

Comment: I ended up winging it since the cube was completely stuck. By wiggling one of the corners I was able to take it out and then the other pieces followed. It’s not to hard to put back together, you just have to pay attention as there are a lot of small spacers inside that could easily be lost.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need to disassemble it, after all, the child who messed it up didn't.

Twist the shifted layer about a quarter turn. This puts it at about 45 degrees compared to the adjacent middle layer. There should now be enough room for you to shift the gear of one of the edges of the middle layer by one tooth relative to the twisted layer. This will distort the cube and lock it up. It may be under so much tension that it won't stay that way and slip back, but try to keep that from happening. Do the same for the other three edges in the middle layer one by one, and after the last edge is skipped a gear tooth the cube should be okay again.